# How to get selected time in input - HTML Calendar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a project where I should make a calendar based on a .PSD file. So, the syntax was made, also html and css, but now I need to get that value on my input.

I need to get selected date on an input but I don't know how. I need to have a format like this: dd/mm/yyyy.

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  width:780px;  
}
#navigator {
  margin-top:0px;
  width: 461px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
#arrowleftrsv {
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #ABABAB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#arrowleftrsv:hover {
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000000;
}
#arrowrightrsv {
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #ABABAB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#arrowrightrsv:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000000;
}

#monthname {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: mybellgothic !important;
    font-size: 31px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    background-color: rgb(253, 245, 222);
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.left-arrow-img{
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px
}
.right-arrow-img{
  right: 150px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
.close-arrow-img{
    bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}

.close-arrow-img2{
      bottom: 23px;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
}

.circle-arrow-img{
      right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
#calendar {
  height: 550px;
  width: 434px; 
}
#daynameblock {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:5px;
  width: 461px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: mybellgothic;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  
}

.sept-month {
    left: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
}
.dayname{
  margin: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: mybellgothic !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.weekendname {
  margin: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: mybellgothic !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
#daysblock {
    height: 393px;
    width: 461px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.weekdays a {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: mybellgothic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 12px;
}

.weekdays a:focus {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: none;
}

.first-day{
  color: #bdbdbd !important;
}
.selected-day{
  background-color: #c33919 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
.second-day{
  background-color: #494949 !important;
  color: #676767 !important;
  }
.weekend a {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: mybellgothic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 12px;
}

.modal-content{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.modal-header{
  border-bottom: none;
}

.weekend a:focus {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: none;
}

.weekdays a:hover {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

.weekend a:hover {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navigator">
      <div id="arrowleftrsv"><a href="#"><img class="left-arrow-img" src="images/left-arrow.png"></a></div>
      <div id="arrowrightrsv"><a href="#"><img class="right-arrow-img" src="images/right-arrow.png"></a></div>
      <div id="arrowrightrsv"><a href="#"><img class="circle-arrow-img" src="images/checked.png" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></a></div>
      <div id="arrowrightrsv"><a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><img class="close-arrow-img" src="images/close.png"></a></div>
      <div id="monthname"><p class="sept-month">Sept.&nbsp;&nbsp;2013</p></div>  
    </div>
    <div id="calendar">
    <div id="daynameblock">
      <div class="dayname">Mon</div>
      <div class="dayname">Tue</div>
      <div class="dayname">Wed</div>
      <div class="dayname">Thu</div>
      <div class="dayname">Fri</div>
      <div class="weekendname">Sat</div>
      <div class="weekendname">Sun</div>
    </div>
    <div id="daysblock">
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">28</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">29</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">30</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">31</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">1</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">2</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">3</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">4</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">5</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">6</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="selected-day" href="#" tabindex="1">7</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">8</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">9</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">10</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">11</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">12</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">13</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">14</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="second-day" href="#" tabindex="1">15</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">16</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">17</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">18</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">19</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">20</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">21</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">22</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">23</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">24</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">25</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">26</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">27</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">28</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">29</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">30</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">1</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">2</a></div>

      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">3</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">4</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">5</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day"tabindex="1">6</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">7</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">8</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"></div>
    </div>
```

So, I need to pick selected date in an input.

Comment: Why don´t you use a library and personalize it? in your case I see great this one https://fullcalendar.io/ , if not you have to use for example data-attributes to get the month, the year etc, I think will be more complicated...

Comment: Hey. I only need that month, not a full calendar with dates. That's why I used HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use event-delegation to get the content of the clicked cell and then construct a string based on circumstantial information. How to get the day is shown below.

```js
const daysBlock = document.getElementById('daysblock');
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];

daysBlock.onclick = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const day = e.target.closest('a').textContent;
  input.value = days[new Date(`2013,09,${day}`).getDay()] + ', ' + day;
};
```

```css
#wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:50px;
  width:780px;  
}
#navigator {
  margin-top:0px;
  width: 461px;
  margin-bottom: -5px;
}
#arrowleftrsv {
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #ABABAB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#arrowleftrsv:hover {
  display:block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000000;
}
#arrowrightrsv {
  height: 24px;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #ABABAB;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#arrowrightrsv:hover {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: x-large;
  color: #000000;
}

#monthname {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-family: mybellgothic !important;
    font-size: 31px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    background-color: rgb(253, 245, 222);
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

.left-arrow-img{
  left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px
}
.right-arrow-img{
  right: 150px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
.close-arrow-img{
    bottom: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
}

.close-arrow-img2{
      bottom: 23px;
    position: relative;
    left: 80px;
}

.circle-arrow-img{
      right: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
#calendar {
  height: 550px;
  width: 434px; 
}
#daynameblock {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:5px;
  width: 461px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: mybellgothic;
  color: #2e2e2e;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  
}

.sept-month {
    left: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
}
.dayname{
  margin: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: mybellgothic !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
.weekendname {
  margin: 1px;
  height: 35px;
  width: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-family: mybellgothic !important;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #2e2e2e;
}
#daysblock {
    height: 393px;
    width: 461px;
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    padding-left: 3px;
}
.weekdays a {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: mybellgothic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 12px;
}

.weekdays a:focus {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: none;
}

.first-day{
  color: #bdbdbd !important;
}
.selected-day{
  background-color: #c33919 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
.second-day{
  background-color: #494949 !important;
  color: #676767 !important;
  }
.weekend a {
    height: 65px;
    width: 65px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-family: mybellgothic;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 12px;
}

.modal-content{
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
}

.modal-header{
  border-bottom: none;
}

.weekend a:focus {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: none;
}

.weekdays a:hover {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
    outline-offset: -4px;
}

.weekend a:hover {
  background: #c33a29;
  outline: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  outline-offset: -4px;
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navigator">
      <div id="arrowleftrsv"><a href="#"><img class="left-arrow-img" src="images/left-arrow.png"></a></div>
      <div id="arrowrightrsv"><a href="#"><img class="right-arrow-img" src="images/right-arrow.png"></a></div>
      <div id="arrowrightrsv"><a href="#"><img class="circle-arrow-img" src="images/checked.png" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></a></div>
      <div id="arrowrightrsv"><a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><img class="close-arrow-img" src="images/close.png"></a></div>
      <div id="monthname"><p class="sept-month">Sept.&nbsp;&nbsp;2013</p></div>  
    </div>
    <div id="calendar">
    <div id="daynameblock">
      <div class="dayname">Mon</div>
      <div class="dayname">Tue</div>
      <div class="dayname">Wed</div>
      <div class="dayname">Thu</div>
      <div class="dayname">Fri</div>
      <div class="weekendname">Sat</div>
      <div class="weekendname">Sun</div>
    </div>
    <div id="daysblock">
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">28</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">29</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">30</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">31</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">1</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">2</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">3</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">4</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">5</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">6</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="selected-day" href="#" tabindex="1">7</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">8</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">9</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">10</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">11</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">12</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">13</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">14</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="second-day" href="#" tabindex="1">15</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">16</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">17</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">18</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">19</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">20</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">21</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">22</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">23</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a href="#" tabindex="1">24</a></div>
      
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">25</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">26</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">27</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">28</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">29</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a href="#" tabindex="1">30</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">1</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">2</a></div>

      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">3</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">4</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">5</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day"tabindex="1">6</a></div>
      <div class="weekdays"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">7</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"><a class="first-day" tabindex="1">8</a></div>
      <div class="weekend"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hey, it's working but I have some questions: 1. Can I get the result in a input field instead of console log? And the second , can I get the result in that form : Mon ( the day of selected day), the selected day( number), + a default formula with /09/2013? because I can only select days from 1 to 30 of september, 2013. And it could be more specific for me.

Comment: To insert the value into an input field you could do (provided its referenced by a variable named input) `input.value = value_from_earlier`. To get the name of the day you need to parse a date and call the `getDay()` method on it.

Comment: I updated my example to your specification. You still need a mechanism to automatically get year and month.

Comment: It's working fine like that : `input.value = days[new Date(`2013/09/${day}`).getDay()] + ' ' + day +'/09/2013';`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datepiker like below. You can also look at [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for the full documentation

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var DateObject = new Date('2019-07-01');
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  changeMonth: false,
  changeYear: false,
  stepMonths: 0,
  onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
   {
     alert(dateText);
   }
  });
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate", DateObject);
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>datepicker demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div id="datepicker"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need a full calendar, I only need that month from 2013 haha.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: thank you sir, it's working, but it's way much better for me to use only javascript for my project, but I will keep your solution on my mind for future projects ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
$(".weekdays").on('click', function() {
    var day = $(this).text();
    var year = $("#monthname p").text().split(";")[1];
    var month = $("#monthname").data('month');
    var date =  new Date(year, month, day);
    alert(date.tostring());
 });
```

Just add the ***data-month*** property on your monthname  div in html.

```
<div id="monthname" data-month="8"><p class="sept-month" >Sept.&nbsp;&nbsp;2013</p></div>
```

> Month in JavaScript is 0 based wired but something to remember

You can customize it depending upon your usecase.

Hope this helps...

Comment: thank you for your answer, maybe I did something wrong but doesn't work for me :( https://codepen.io/andreixfr/pen/ExxzYrd

Comment: That was my bad i corrected the solution, this should give you the date on click, but instead of seting up to some input try alerting it, as i cant see any input in your html.